# Deleting feature from geographic database using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How do I delete a selected feature from database when it is clicked on in the ArcGIS API for javascript?

Comment: mil gracias por la colaboración, excelente ejemplo. Saludos ---
Translation (via Google Translate) thanks for the collaboration, excellent example. regards

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 'feature' instead of 'feature class', then the default editing widget for the javascript api handles deleting features.

Here is a link to the Esri sample:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/ed_default_editingwidget

Comment: YES i use already editing widget but i don't able to capture the function of delete in button delete to check if map have graphic or not

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking, but if you want to handle the delete manually and check whether a graphic is actually selected before trying to delete, you could do something like this:

```
var myFeatureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KGS_OilGasFields_Kansas/MapServer/0",{
    mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

//get the selected graphic from the feature layer, only gets the first graphic, [0]
var targetGraphic = myFeatureLayer .getSelectedFeatures()[0];
//check if there is a selected graphic
if (targetGraphic) {
    //Delete subblock feature
    myFeatureLayer.applyEdits(null, null, [targetGraphic], function (adds, updates, deletes) {
        dojo.byId('infoPane').innerHTML = "Deleted feature successfully, OBJECTID: " + deletes[0].objectId;
        //operationalLayer.refresh();
    }, dojo.byId('infoPane').innerHTML = "Error when deleting feature");
}
```

Comment: this function can delete feature layer from geo database . can me ask what is subblockEditFeatureLayer mean

Comment: Just a name for the feature layer-- you could call it myFeatureLayer. See edit above..